# encountering a logoff warning message in a Remote Desktop Services session and wish to disable it

Tags: registry, logout, remote-desktop, rdp, winlogon

Requirement is to logoff RDP session. I used quser to find session ID and logged off using command "logoff ".
When system logged off warning is thrown saying "Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended. Another user connected to the remote computer, so your connection was lost. Try connecting again, or contact your network administrator."
How can I disable this warning?

I tried below commands, but didn't work for me.

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v ForceAutoLogon /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f